# CSS: Box-Shadow Transition Multiple Shadows

Tags: html, css

So I have a button with initial shadow set. I want to transition the shadow on hover into another value of shadow.

```css
button {
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  padding:10px;
  margin:5px;
  border:none;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #dde4ef, -10px -10px 20px white;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-in;
}

button:hover{
  box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 20px #dde4ef, inset -10px -10px 20px white;
}
```

```html
<button>This Button</button>
```

Its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Prepare** your inset shadows by using `inset 0 0 0 transparent, inset 0 0 0 transparent,`

```css
button {
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  padding:10px;
  margin:5px;
  border:none;
  border-radius:10px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow:
     inset 0 0 0 transparent, inset 0 0 0 transparent, /* Prepared inset shadows */
     10px 10px 20px #dde4ef, -10px -10px 20px white;   /* Outer shadows */
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-in;
}

button:hover{
  box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 20px #dde4ef, inset -10px -10px 20px white;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">HOVER ME</button>
```